# Minikube got stuck when creating container

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I recently got started to learn Kubernetes by using Minikube locally in my Mac. Previously, I was able to start a local Kubernetes cluster with Minikube 0.10.0, created a deployment and viewed Kubernetes dashboard.

Yesterday I tried to delete the cluster and re-did everything from scratch. However, I found I cannot get the assets deployed and cannot view the dashboard. From what I saw, everything seemed to get stuck during container creation.

After I ran `minikube start`, it reported

```
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
```

When I ran `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`, it reported (pay attention to the STATUS column):

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                          READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          51s
```

`docker ps` showed nothing:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

`minikube status` tells me the VM and cluster are running:

```
minikubeVM: Running
localkube: Running
```

If I tried to create a deployment and an autoscaler, I was told they were created successfully:

```
kubectl create -f configs
deployment "hello-minikube" created
horizontalpodautoscaler "hello-minikube-autoscaler" created

$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
default       hello-minikube-661011369-1pgey   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          1m
default       hello-minikube-661011369-91iyw   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          1m
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube      0/1       ContainerCreating   0          21m
```

When exposing the service, it said:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
service "hello-minikube" exposed

$ kubectl get service
NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
hello-minikube   10.0.0.32    <nodes>       8080/TCP   6s
kubernetes       10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    22m
```

When I tried to access the service, I was told:

```
curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
```

`docker ps` still showed nothing. It looked to me everything got stuck when creating a container. I tried some other ways to work around this issue:

1. Upgraded to minikube 0.11.0
2. Use the xhyve driver instead of the Virtualbox driver
3. Delete everything cached, like ~/.minikube, ~/.kube, and the cluster, and re-try

None of them worked for me.

Kubernetes is still new to me and I would like to know:

1. How can I troubleshoot this kind of issue?
2. What could be the cause of this issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out to be a network problem in my case.

The pod status is "ContainerCreating", and I found during container creation, docker image will be pulled from gcr.io, which is inaccessible in China (blocked by GFW). Previous time it worked for me because I happened to connect to it via a VPN.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you tell me how you resolved this issue? It would be of great help

Comment: @NSP For me, since it is caused by a network accessibility issue, I simply connect to VPN to work around this issue.

Comment: so should i delete the existing minikube setup and then start a fresh install by connecting to the VPN? (a minikube delete followed by a minikube start? )

Comment: @NSP I don't remember the exact detail any more, but give it a try :)

Comment: thanks a lot for that answer. I am able to access the minikube dashboard now after having used a dongle instead of intranet. You were right, there seems to be a network accessibility issue. I had spent more than a week trying to debug this. But finally your answer came to my rescue :)

Comment: You can do `minikube start --image-repository=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers` in China, it uses aliyun gcr.io mirrors.

Comment: while the answer is correct, it's more helpful how to figure out whats the problem. People with a different problem might also get stuck with the same error message.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't try `minikube` but I use `kubernetes`. With the information provided it is difficult to say the cause of the issue. Your `minikube` has no problem in creating resources but `ContainerCreating` is a problem related to `docker` daemon or improper communication between `kube-api` and `docker` daemon or some problem with `kubelet`.

You can try the following command:

```bash
kubectl describe po POD_NAME
```

This will give you the POD's events. Maybe this will provide a path to the root cause of issue.

You may also check the logs of `kubelet` to get the events.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on Windows, but it was related to an `NTLM proxy`. I deleted the `minikube` VM then recreated it with the correct proxy settings for my `CNTLM` installation:

```bash
minikube start \
--docker-env http_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128 \
--docker-env https_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128 \
--docker-env no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,192.168.99.100
```

See https://blog.alexellis.io/minikube-behind-proxy/

Answer (score 1):

The horizontalpodautoscaler (hpa) requires heapster to use.  You'll need to run heapster in minikube for that to work.  You can always debug these kinds of issues with `minikube logs` or interactively through the dashboard found at `minikube dashboard`.

You can find the steps to run heapster and grafana at https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster

Answer (score 0):

For me, it takes several minutes before I see the `ContainerCreating` problem. After executing the following command:

```bash
systemctl status kube-controller-manager.service
```

I get this error:

> Sync "default/redis-master-2229813293" failed with unable to create pods: No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Set the service account with token
2. Remove the `ServiceAccount` setting of `KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL` in api-server